# How to get all cups avaible variables to set on cups4j?

Tags: java, printing, cups, cups4j

On cups4j I can set variables such as:

`attributes.put("job-attributes", "print-quality:enum:4#fit-to-page:boolean:true#sheet-
collate:keyword:collated");`

How do I find out all variables that can be set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thiago, I'm trying to get to grips with cups4j too.

Unfortunately, cups4j is one of the most poorly documented Open Source projects I've ever seen.

I found some of the attributes in RFC 2911.
(Internet Printing Protocol/1.1: Model and Semantics)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911

Addendum: just noticed RFC 8011 which supersedes RFC 2911:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8011

If I find out more, I'll post it here.

Found something @ IANA...

http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipp-registrations/ipp-registrations.xhtml